# How to save checkbox as 'checked' once user registers or save account details

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce

For new users: A checkbox has been added to the Woocommerce Registration form. Once user checks that checkbox it needs to display checked in the WordPress Profile of that user as well as the account details tabs (Above the save details button).

For Current users: The checkbox is unchecked in their WordPress Profiles as well as their Woocommerce account details tab (Above the save details button).

Currently, I am able to check the checkbox upon registering, which then shows that it is checked in my WordPress Profile, however not checked on my Woocommerce Account Details Tab.

Hope this makes more sense.

Here is the code I am using below:

```
 // user consent on registration
// 
// Add the checkbox to registration form
add_action( 'register_form', 'foo_add_privacy_policy_field' );

function foo_add_privacy_policy_field() {
    ?>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo_privacy_policy" id="foo_privacy_policy" class="checkbox" style="float: left; height: 50px;" />
  <label for="foo_privacy_policy">
    <?php _e( 'Privacy Policy', 'foo' ) ?>
  </label>
</p>
<?php
}

// Validate the checkbox value in the registration form so that it is required
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'foo_privacy_policy_auth', 10, 3 );

function foo_privacy_policy_auth( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {
    if ( !isset( $_POST[ 'foo_privacy_policy' ] ) ):
        $errors->add( 'policy_error', "<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please accept the privacy policy." );
    return $errors;
    endif;
    return $errors;
}

// Fill the meta 'foo_privacy_policy' with the value of the checkbox
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'foo_privacy_policy_save' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'foo_privacy_policy_save' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'foo_privacy_policy_save' );
add_action( 'user_register', 'foo_privacy_policy_save' );

function foo_privacy_policy_save( $user_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST[ 'foo_privacy_policy' ] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'foo_privacy_policy', $_POST[ 'foo_privacy_policy' ] );
    } else {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'foo_privacy_policy', 'off' );
    }
}

// Add the checkbox to user profile home
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'foo_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'foo_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'foo_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'foo_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function foo_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {
    ?>
<h3>
  <?php esc_html_e( 'Privacy Policy', 'foo' ); ?>
</h3>
<table class="form-table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="foo_privacy_policy" id="foo_privacy_policy" class="checkbox" value='1' style="float: left; height: 50px;" <?php if (esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('foo_privacy_policy', $user->ID))=='on' ){ echo "checked"; } ?> />
      <label for="foo_privacy_policy">
        <?php _e( 'Privacy Policy', 'foo' ) ?>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please read it again and improve it. The WooCommerce account page just displays things from orders, products or users (aka user meta infos).

Comment: Let me know if the above makes more sense...